# OCaml batteries included can't be built on Mac OS X 10.6.6

Tags: macos, ocaml

I tried to build OCaml batteries included 1.3.0 on my Mac OS X 10.6.6 (MacBook Air3,2) but couldn't.
OCaml itself and denpending libraries versions are as follows:

- OCaml : 3.11.2
- findlib : 1.2.6
- OUnit : 1.1.0
- camomile : 0.8.1
- make : 3.81

I'm not using GODI for installation. Are there anyone who runs OCaml batteries included on you Mac and if there are, can you let me know your libraries versions? Further more, could you find any solution for fixing this error?

```
% make all
cp -f src/batCamomile-0.8.1.ml src/batCamomile.ml
test ! -e src/batteries_config.ml || rm src/batteries_config.ml
ocamlbuild syntax.otarget byte.otarget src/batteries_help.cmo META shared.otarget
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ ocamlfind ocamlopt -shared -linkall -package camomile,num,str -o src/batteries_uni.cmxs src/batteries_uni.cmxa
ld: warning: -read_only_relocs cannot be used with x86_64
ld: codegen problem, can't use rel32 to external symbol _caml_negf_mask in .L101 from src/batteries_uni.a(batFloat.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error during linking
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 479 targets (478 cached) in 00:00:01.
make: *** [all] Error 10
```

Thanks,
Yoshi a.k.a. ymotongpoo

Comment: I did build Batteries 1.3.0 with OCaml 3.12.1+dev5. I never saw an error like yours. This thread might be relevant: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ocaml.godi/462

Comment: Some think it's a bug in GCC. Get the latest XCode. I built it using gcc 4.2.1. See http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=24612#p371950

Comment: Hi Mitas! Of course I've checked the link. I turned `BATTERIES_NATIVE_SHLIB=false` and that actually make it possible to `make all` successfully but `make test qtest` fails with creating `test_mods.ml` and more. And also my GCC version is latest XCode's one, gcc 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, you must disable native shared library building.  Use the `BATTERIES_NATIVE_SHLIB=no` argument to Make to accomplish this:

```
$ make all install BATTERIES_NATIVE_SHLIB=no
```

The GODI package sets this parameter by default on Mac, but you must set it manually when building from source yourself.  **You need to set this parameter on every invocation of `make`** (or set it as an environment variable).

Finally, I highly recommending using GODI.  It makes managing an OCaml installation far easier than doing it by hand.

Comment: Yes, it actually worked for `make all` and `make install`. But as I commented above, `make test qtest` doesn't work with that option. If the tests doesn't matter anything then I ignore them. Did you try `make test qtest` with that option?

Comment: @ymotongpoo no - I don't have a Mac (and neither do the other core devs, so far as I know), so the Mac fixes have been based entirely on reports from users.  It sounds, though, like the `test` and `qtest` options are bypassing the native-shlib disabling logic.  Can you file a bug in the [GitHub bug tracker](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/issues)?

Comment: ah, okay I got it. On my Debian environment I could build OCaml batteries included 1.3.0. Then, I register the bug into the bug tracker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I reported to bug tracker and the cause of `make test qtest` failure is `-n` option of echo command.
https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/issues#issue/122

At first in OS X, option `BATTERIES_NATIVE_SHLIB=false` has to be set. And still, you need to modify Makefile to run test successfully.
Latest version in the repository has been fixed but if you want to build 1.3.0 tarball, modify Makefile as follows:

```
#put all the testing modules in a library
qtest/test_mods.mllib: $(TESTABLE)
-  echo -n "Quickcheck Tests \c" > $@
+  echo "Quickcheck Tests \c" > $@
   echo $(patsubst src/%.ml,%_t, $(TESTABLE)) >> $@
```

or, you can use `/bin/echo`

```
#put all the testing modules in a library
qtest/test_mods.mllib: $(TESTABLE)
-  echo -n "Quickcheck Tests \c" > $@
+  /bin/echo -n "Quickcheck Tests \c" > $@
   echo $(patsubst src/%.ml,%_t, $(TESTABLE)) >> $@
```

Both way work.